# Extract string between two brackets, including nested brackets in python

Tags: python, regex

How to extract string between two brackets, including the nested brackets.

There is a string:

```
""res = sqr(if((a>b)&(a<c),(a+b)*c,(a-b)*c)+if()+if()...)""
```

How can I extract the all the contents of `if()` as following:

```
["if((a>b)&(a<c),(a+b)*c,(a-b)*c)","if()","if()",...]
```

The format is not fixed, the string may includes multi-`if`s. So I want to know if there is a pattern that can match the substring. I'll try to give my solution later. thanks.

My solution, if there is any better method, please point out to me:

```
def extractIfFunc(condStr):

startIndex = [m.start() for m in re.finditer('if\(',condStr)]
parts = []
for index in startIndex:
    current = []
    bracket_level = 0
    for s in condStr[index+3:]:
        if s != '(' and s != ')' and bracket_level >= 0:
            current.append(s)
        elif s == '(':
            current.append(s)
            bracket_level += 1
        elif s == ')':
            bracket_level -= 1 
            if bracket_level < 0:
                current.append(s)
                break
            else:
                current.append(s)     
    parts.append('if('+''.join(current))
return parts
```

Comment: If all your inputs are in the form "varname = funcname(expression)", then it's quite easy - just find the position of the first opening paren and you're basically done. Now if you want to be able to parse arbitrary expressions / statements, you'll need a proper parser for this language, whatever it is.

Comment: https://tomassetti.me/parsing-in-python/

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers, yes, that's what i exactly want to do.

Comment: @Jimmy "yes, that's what i exactly want to do" => what ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> s = """res = sqr(if((a>b)&(a<c),(a+b)*c,(a-b)*c)+if()+if()...)"""
>>> re.findall(r'if\((?:[^()]*|\([^()]*\))*\)', s)
['if((a>b)&(a<c),(a+b)*c,(a-b)*c)', 'if()', 'if()']
```

For such patterns, better to use `VERBOSE` flag:

```
>>> lvl2 = re.compile('''
...          if\(            #literal if(
...            (?:           #start of non-capturing group
...             [^()]*       #non-parentheses characters
...             |            #OR
...             \([^()]*\)   #non-nested pair of parentheses
...            )*            #end of non-capturing group, 0 or more times
...          \)              #literal )
...          ''', flags=re.X)
>>> re.findall(lvl2, s)
['if((a>b)&(a<c),(a+b)*c,(a-b)*c)', 'if()', 'if()']
```

To match any number of nested pairs, you can use [regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) module, see [Recursive Regular Expressions](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-recursion.html)

Comment: I have just tried this in a python fiddle and it does not work. It returns: `['if((a>b)&(a`

Comment: I just checked with Python 3.11 and it works. Not sure what you meant by "fiddle". And here's an online demo: https://regex101.com/r/3Ikqwh/1

Answer (score 1):

```
st = """res = sqr(if((a>b)&(a<c),(a+b)*c,(a-b)*c))"""

print(st[10:][:-1])
```

OUTPUT:

```
if((a>b)&(a<c),(a+b)*c,(a-b)*c)
```

**EDIT:**

For a *generic* approach:

```
import re
st = """res = sqr(if((a>b)&(a<c),(a+b)*c,(a-b)*c))"""
pattern = "\((.*)\)"
print(re.compile(pattern).search(st).group(1))
```

Where:

`\(` matches the character `(` literally (case sensitive)

1st Capturing Group  `(.*)`

`.*` matches any character (except for line terminators)

`\)` matches the character `)` literally

OUTPUT:

```
if((a>b)&(a<c),(a+b)*c,(a-b)*c)
```

[regexTester](https://regex101.com/r/fv0DfR/7)

Comment: what about `""result = sqrt(if((a>b)&(a<c),(a+b)*c,(a-b)*c))""` ? This is not a global answer!

Comment: It looked like a fixed string manipulation, however I will edit and add a global approach after lunch, cheers

Comment: Enjoy your meal :)

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
st[st.find('(')+1:st.rfind(')')]
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
def extractIfFunc(condStr):
    for i, segment in enumerate(a.split("if")):
        if i == 0:
            continue

        s, n = -1, 0
        for i, c in enumerate(segment):
            if c == '(':
                s = i if s < 0 else s
                n += 1
            elif c == ')':
                n = n - 1 if n > 0 else 0
                if n == 0 and s > -1:
                    yield "if(%s)" % segment[s + 1:i]
                    break


a = """res = sqr(if((a>b)&(a<c),(a+b)*c,(a-b)*c)+if()+if()...)"""

for segment in extractIfFunc(a):
    print(segment)
```

**NOTE:**

This is not a real parser. If you want to create a parser that matches **LALR(1) grammar**, maybe the [PLY](https://github.com/dabeaz/ply) is what you are looking for. It can help you to build a complete parser.